# Rails 4.0.0 - Got "no implicit conversion of nil into String"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Just installed a brand new Rails 4.0.0 app and I got this error (https://gist.github.com/hartator/6404820) on `http://0.0.0.0:3000`:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String

activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:24:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:24:in `new'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:24:in `sqlite3_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:440:in `new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:450:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:421:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:356:in `block in checkout'
/Users/asa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:355:in `checkout'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block in connection'
/Users/asa/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:264:in `connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
```

My database.yml: http://pastebin.com/JM5TNmNU

I haven't done anything yet to the vanilla rails code. Any idea what could be the issue?

Using:

- Rails 4.0.0
- Ruby 2.0.0p195
- Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Comment: Is it full log? I just don't see any error.

Comment: Sorry, it was in title forgot to put it in the body.

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your `config/database.yml` file because the error occures in the part that initialize db.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've added to the post my database.yml (http://pastebin.com/JM5TNmNU), it seems fine though, any idea what's wrong in it?

Comment: Did you run bundle install already?

Comment: Looking at the source code for this (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb), it looks like config[:database] isn't found. What environment is your rails app running?

Comment: `bundle install` run smoothly and I am in development environment. Here a more detail gist: https://gist.github.com/hartator/6404820

Comment: Did you run `rake db:create`?

Comment: Try `gem pristine sqlite3`

Comment: I got the same error when I run rake `db:create` but when I've ran `gem pristine sqlite3` it solves everything. Thanks man!

Comment: Nice! I posted an answer so you can aceept it. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds like a problem with your sqlite3 gem installation. Try:

```
gem pristine sqlite3
```

From the RubyGems documentation:

> #### gem pristine
>
> Restores installed gems to pristine condition from files located in the gem cache
>
> Usage
>
> ```
> gem pristine [GEMNAME ...] [options]
> ```

http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem_pristine